# Crystal formula conversion in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008-r2

How to convert the following in ssrs expression:
`INVENTORYDATE <> date(1900,01,01)` --Crystal version

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Fields!INVENTORYDATE.Value <> CDATE("1900-01-01")
```

`CDATE()` function converts a string to date, what lets you compare INVENTORYDATE to the hardcoded date.

Also you can use `DateSerial()` function, which returns a Date value representing a specified year, month, and day, with the time.

```
INVENTORYDATE <> DATESERIAL(1900,01,01)
```

**UPDATE:** Add 630 minutes to `INVENTORYDATE`.

Use this expression:

```
DATEADD(DateInterval.Minute,630,Fields!INVENTORYDATE.Value)
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: thanks.  how can i convert the following in ssrs:   dateadd('n',630,{Command.INVENTORYDATE})-- crystal version